# How to install ubuntu packages offline from installation CD

Tags: 14.04, server, gcc

I have a server with no internet access. I am trying to install the **build-essential** package on the server **offline**. I read on the internet that some packages should be installed from the CD. using **apt-cdrom**. But i don't know how it works.

I read that I have to do this

apt-cdrom add

```
apt-get install build-essential
but it doesn't work.
```

Does any one know how to do it ?

Comment: Can you download it on another computer or phone and transfer it across? I don't think `apt-cdrom` is what you are looking for it still seems to need an internet connection https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the required files from another system which is connected to Internet. For that you have to create a download script from the server.

```
apt-get --allow-unauthenticated -y install --print-uris build-essential | cut -d\' -f2 | grep http:// > download-list
```

This will create a new file named **download-list** in which the required files for download is included.

Now copy this file `download-list` to the system where you have Internet facility.

Run the following command to download all files.

```
wget -c -i ./download-list
```

Now copy all the downloaded **.deb** files to the `/var/cache/apt/` folder of your server. You will need root permission for this.

After this you can install `build-essential` simply as we do regularly.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```